# Installing Hadoop over 5 hard drives on a desktop

Tags: hadoop, installation

I have been working with installing Hadoop. I followed some instruction on a Udemy course, and I installed Hadoop on pseudo distributed mode, on my laptop. It was fairly straightforward.

After that, I started to wonder if I could set up Hadoop on a desktop computer. So went out and bought an empty case and put in a 64 bit, 8 core AMD processor, along with a 50GB SSD hard drive and 4 inexpensive 500GB hard drives. I installed Ubuntu 14.04 on the SSD drive, and put virtual machines on the other drives.

I'm envisioning using my SSD as the master and using my 4 hard drives as nodes. Again, everything is living in the same case.

Unfortunately, and I've been searching everywhere, and I can't find any tutorials, guides, books, etc, that describe setting up Hadoop in this manner. It seems like most everything I've found that details installation of Hadoop is either a simple pseudo distributed setup (which I've already done), or else the instructions jump straight to large scale commercial applications. I'm still learning the basics, clearly, but I'd like to play in this sort-of in between place.

Has anyone done this before, and/or come across any documentation / tutorials / etc that describe how to set Hadoop up in this way? Many thanks in advance for the help.

Comment: Can't get you, describe briefly?

Comment: For future reference:
http://mail-archives.apache.org/mod_mbox/hadoop-common-user/201009.mbox/%3CA3EF3F6AF24E204B812D1D24CCC8D71A03688F76@mse16be2.mse16.exchange.ms%3E

Answer (score 1):

- You can **run** hadoop in different VM's which are located in different drives in the same system.
- But you need to allocate **same configurations** for all the master and slave nodes
- Also ensure that all the VM's having **different ip** addresses.
- You can get different IP addresses by **connecting** your master computer to the **LAN** or you need to disable some functionality in VM machines in order to get different IP addresses.

Answer (score 1):

if you done the hadoop installation in pseduo mode means then follow the below steps this may help you.

MULTINODE :

Configure the hosts in the network using the following settings in the host file. This has to be done in all machine [in namenode too].

## sudo vi /etc/hosts

add the following lines in the file:

yourip1 master

yourip2 slave01

yourip3 slave02

yourip4 slave03

yourip5 slave04

[Save and exit – type ESC then :wq ]

Change the hostname for the namenode and datanodes.

## sudo vi /etc/hostname

For master machine [namenode ] – master

For other machines – slave01 and slave02 and slave03 and slave04 and slave 05

Restart the machines in order to get the settings related to the network applied.

## sudo shutdown -r now

Copy the keys from the master node to all datanodes, so as this will help to access the machines without asking for permissions everytime.

```
    #ssh-copy-id –i ~/.ssh/id_rsa.pub hduser@slave01
    #ssh-copy-id –i ~/.ssh/id_rsa.pub hduser@slave02
    #ssh-copy-id –i  ~/.ssh/id_rsa.pub hduser@slave03
    #ssh-copy-id –i  ~/.ssh/id_rsa.pub hduser@slave04
```

Now we are about to configure the hadoop configuration settings, so navigate to the ‘conf’ folder.

## cd ~/hadoop/etc

Edit the slaves file within the hadoop directory.

## vi ~/hadoop/conf/slaves

And add the below :

```
master

slave01

slave02

slave03

slave04
```

Now update localhost to master in core-site.xml,hdfs-site.xml,mapred-site.xml and yarn-site.xml

Now copy the files from the hadoop/etc/hadoop folder from master to slave machines.

then format you namenode in all machines.

and start the hadoop services.

I given you the some clues for how to configure the hadoop multinode cluster.

Answer (score 0):

Never tried, but if you type `ifconfig` then it gives you `same ipaddress` on all the `vm machines` in hard drives. So this may not be the better option to go..
You can try creating Hadoop Cluster on [Amazon EC2](http://aws.amazon.com/) for free using this step by step guide [**HERE**](http://www.edureka.co/blog/install-apache-hadoop-cluster/)
Or Video guide [**HERE**](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=AdMzfJB9pDM)
Hope it helps!